# Write down a pair of bounded functions f,g :[0,1] to the reals such that ||fg|| is less than ||f||*||g||

Tags: real-analysis

I’m struggling to find two functions that will satisfy this equality. Thanks
I’m using supnorms here, where ||f||= sup (|f(x)|)

Answer (score 3):

Take $f=\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2})}$ and $g=\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$.Here,$\chi$ denotes indicator function of a set.Then $fg=0$ but $||f||=||g||=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \colon [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g \colon [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the functions defined by
$$
f(t) \colon= t \ \mbox{ for all } t \in [0, 1],
$$
and 
$$
g(t) \colon = 1 - t \ \mbox{ for all } t \in [0, 1].
$$
Then 
$$
\lVert f \rVert = 1 = \lVert g \rVert.
$$

And, the function $fg \colon [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$
\big( fg \big)(t) \colon= f(t) g(t) = t (1-t) = t - t^2 \ \mbox{ for all } t \in [0, 1].
$$
For all $t \in [0, 1]$, we note that
$$
\big( fg \big)^\prime(t) = 1 - 2t.
$$
Thus
$$
\big( fg \big)^\prime (t) \ 
\begin{cases} > 0 \ & \mbox{ if } 0 \leq t < \frac{1}{2}, \\ 
0 \ & \mbox{ if } t = \frac{1}{2}, \\ 
< 0 \ & \mbox{ if } \frac{1}{2} < t \leq 1 
\end{cases}.
$$
Thus $fg$ is strictly increasing on the closed interval  $\left[0, \frac{1}{2} \right]$ and strictly decreasing on the closed interval $\left[ \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right]$. So $fg$ has a relative maximum values of 
$$
\big( fg \big) \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4},
$$
and relative minimum value of
$$
\big( fg \big)(0) = 0 = \big( fg \big)(1).
$$
Thus we can conclude that
$$
0 \leq \big( fg \big)(t) \leq \frac{1}{4}
$$
for all $t \in [0, 1]$.

Therefore
$$
\big\lVert fg \big\rVert = \frac14 < \lVert f \rVert \times \lVert g \rVert.
$$